# Eclipse - preview source in separate window on mouse click?

Tags: editor, eclipse-juno, eclipse-adt

I'm looking for a way to be able to preview code related to what's under my cursor in a separate window when I click the mouse/touchpad. Eg. definition for methods / member variables etc. 
Something like the results of Ctrl+Click but instead of opening the file in my main editor window, I'd like to see the results in a small window below the main editor window (a 'code preview' window).
Ideally, the 'code preview' window doesn't hide any code surrounding the preview of the item under the cursor.
This happens for eg. in Source Insight & VSlick. It gives the ability to browse another section of the code in a small window while the main source is open in the main window. 
I find it very useful.

Is there any way / plugin etc to do this in ADT/Eclipse ? 
I'm new to Eclipse and using the ADT flavor (Eclipse Platform 4.2.1.v20130118) for Android Java dev.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Press Shift and hover the mouse cursor over the method or variable - it will show a small popup with the source preview.
You must be sure it is enabled in Preferences (Preferences->Java->Editor->Hovers, "Source" line should be checked).

Checked with Eclipse 4.4.